# Flow Lookup - Account Team Member

Tags: process-builder, account, flow, visual-flows, account-teams

Cant see what I am doing wrong here - I have a flow that is supposed to be looking up to the Account Team Member Object - I am passing the the AccountID and TeamMemberRole - the flow never finds a record

I've tried using a Fast Lookup - but get the same error - very annoying - cant see what the problem is here

I have set up the below Record Lookup in my Flow 
[image: Flow Component]

It looks to the Account Team Member Object

Filter field values are passed from a separate Process Builder 
(based on error files Builder seems to be passing the correct values)

The 2 filter fields are variables - as such 
{!AccountID} = a text Variable assigned from my Process Builder (Input & Output Values)
{!AccountShareID} = Text Variable  (Input & Output Values)

On my test account I have a user in the Account Team which meet these criteria 
However when I trigger the flow it always fails with the below error message

error file received

RECORD QUERY: AccountTeamLookup
Find one AccountTeamMember record where:
AccountId Equals {!AccountID} (0018A000007tyKdQAI)
TeamMemberRole Equals Acquisitions Manager
Result
Failed to find record.

If i set a report to search on the above values i get the expected result

I want to pass the AccountMemberID onto another Component to delete the entry

Added Full Flow here 
[image: ![Full Flow]

Comment: can you explain clearly @podger

Comment: @user36188 - i've updated this a bit - what part is unclear?

Comment: is there any relationships is there between the components,what is not showing?,it is showing teamnumber role equals Aquisition Manager

Comment: added the flow there - the only other variable is the PB - all it is doing is calling the flow & assigning the AccountID

Comment: the record what you are searching in recordlookup that Record is stored in {!accountshareid},remove {!accountshareid} from record delete it will works

Comment: no - i cant remove AccountshareID from the delete component =- without replacing it with something?

Comment: what you want to replace?

Comment: So i have 2 parts the Lookup & the Delete - i can remove the accountshareID from the lookup but i cant remove it from the delete - the delete needs something to filter on

Comment: its always the same error -0- RECORD QUERY: AccountTeamLookup
Find one AccountTeamMember record where:
AccountId Equals {!AccountID} (0018A000007tyKdQAI)
TeamMemberRole Equals Acquisitions Manager
Result
Failed to find record.

Comment: create a variable or sobject variable and store the Acquistion Manger id in that variable ,then you filter the Account team lookup object with that variable it will works

Comment: cant use the UserID (or avoiding using it) - I'm removing the user from a lookup to trigger the PB - no ID would be passed and PRIORVALUE causes more errors with PB

Comment: ok carry on,please mention it correctly in the question,error is in pb or flow

Comment: its in the flow - the values i am passing AccountID & TeamMemberRole never find a record to delete

Comment: @Podger Just curios, in your initial condition in Process Builder, where you select an Object on which to trigger it, have you selected the following option: "Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction?"

Comment: @smukov - yes I've have had this ticked/unticked - still seeing the same error